# ASP.NET MVC3 - If Statements in VB

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In [Fredrik's Blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2010/08/01/asp-net-mvc-3-0-preview-1-razor-and-nested-master-pages.aspx), he has an example of a C# if statement

```
@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
    <li><a href="/user/login">Log in</a></li>
} else {
    <li><a href="/user/logout">Log out</a></li>
}
```

But in VB I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing

```
@If (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) Then
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Log Out">
    <div class="alert" title="Alert">
    </div>
    Are you sure?</div>
End If
```

This show's that my internal HTML markup is wrong.

Basically the following is valid

```
@If (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) Then 

End If
```

but anything that goes inside the if statement is considered "code" and not "markup". What I need is to be able to put markup in there.

Does anyone know how to do a proper if statement in Razor VB?

Comment: This answer to a related question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169340/razor-view-engine-quirks-in-vb-net/4171198#4171198

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Lucas pointed me in the right direction.  This seems to be valid

```
@If (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) Then
@<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Log Out">
    <div class="alert" title="Alert"></div>
    <div>Are you sure?</div>
</div>
End If
```