# Converting C# Razor to VB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I'm following the [ASP.NET MVC Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-3) and having started in VB.NET I'm having trouble converting the following razor code:

[image]

I have got

```
<ul>
    @For Each g As MvcApplication1.Genre In Model
        <li> @g.Name </li>
    Next

</ul>
```

but getting

> Attribute Sepcifier is not a complete
>   statement

on both the `<li>` tags. I understand I need to use line continuation but can't figure out where.  I'd be greatful if you can point out the problem.

Comment: are you saying the error is on the `<li> @g.Name </li>` line

Comment: Totally worthless comment, but I ran across the exact same issue in the exact same tutorial. THANKS SO MUCH!!!

Comment: already did. (i like my points too)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put an @ before the `li`:

```
<ul>
    @For Each g As MvcApplication1.Genre In Model
        @<li>@g.Name</li>
    Next
</ul>
```

I would recommend you the [following article](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic).

Answer (score 4):

I think your `<li>` line needs to be prepended with the `@:` operator based on this stack post:

[Razor View Engine Quirks in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169340/razor-view-engine-quirks-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the text tag, which will tell razor views that the following is normal html markup, they are not actually rendered:

```
<ul>
    @For Each g As MvcApplication1.Genre In Model
        <text><li> @g.Name </li></text>
    Next
</ul>
```