# HTML inside @Using block in MVC 3 Razor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Visual Studio raises a error when I place HTML inside the @Using block:

"> expeted"

```
@Using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateForm", New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "textEntered"}))
        @Html.TextBox("textBox1", "Enter text")
        <br />
End Using
```

I'm using MVC 3, Razor as the view engine, and VS2010 express.

What am I missing?

Thanks

UPDATE: answer here [Razor View Engine Quirks in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169340/razor-view-engine-quirks-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VBHTML pages, you need to prefix HTML directly inside of code blocks (such as your `@Using` block) with `@`:

```
@Using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateForm", New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "textEntered"}))
        @Html.TextBox("textBox1", "Enter text")
        @<br />
End Using
```

Comment: I see. That's a shame. My only other option is use a different view engine (aspx for example)?

Comment: @Matti I think it's ridiculous we should have to prefix everything inside a using block with @ only in VB and not C#.

Comment: @Jamie: With all due respect, I think VB is ridiculous.

Comment: @Jamie: This is necessary because of VB.Net's XML literals - the Razor can't tell the difference between an XML literal and HTML markup.