# Javascript code in <script> element within VB Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I'm trying to include some JS in a view within a Razor conditional, but it keeps trying to interpret my JS as VB:

```
@If includeMoreJs Then
    @<script type="text/javascript" src="/some-js-file.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/some-other-js-file.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function someFunction(p) {
            if (p) foo();
            else bar();
        }
    </script>
End If
```

I've also tried this with the `<text>` psuedo element as described here: [Using Razor within JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)

```
@If includeMoreJs Then
    <text>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/some-js-file.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/some-other-js-file.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function someFunction(p) {
            if (p) foo();
            else bar();
        }
    </script>
    </text>
End If
```

but still no luck... How can I get VB to leave my JS alone?

Comment: Odd, I've never had that in C# and surprised `<text>` doesn't work either. Try starting it with `@:` maybe?

Comment: The code looks fine, what error message are you receiving?

Comment: @Rhumborl Yep I tried @: as well.  Still no luck.

Comment: @TrentStewart I'm getting a bunch of errors: all of the errors you would expect to see if you tried to run JS as VB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK having forced myself to create my first ever .vbhtml file, and googling around, you were very nearly there with the `<text>` block.

[This page](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(vb)) is a pretty good resource for VB Razor syntax.

There are two ways around this, depending how much html you have in your `@If`:

**Option 1: `@:`**

This is needed on every line so generally you would only use it if there is only one line in your `If`:

```
@If includeMoreJs Then
    @:<script type="text/javascript" src="/some-js-file.js"></script>
    @:<script type="text/javascript" src="/some-other-js-file.js"></script>
    @:<script type="text/javascript">
    @:    function someFunction(p) {
    @:        if (p) foo();
    @:        else bar();
    @:
    @:</script>
End If
```

.. Very pretty

**Option 2: `@<text>`**

Because VB can have XML as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4171198/1901857), a plain `<text>` will be interpreted as VB code, not razor. So in VB, compared to C#, you need to use `@<text>` to have a block of HTML:

```
@If includeMoreJs Then
    @<text>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/some-js-file.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/some-other-js-file.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function someFunction(p) {
            if (p) foo();
            else bar();
        }
    </script>
    </text>
End If
```

This parses fine.

Comment: Ugh VB...  

@Rhumborl, thank you so much for spending the time on this.  I really appreciate it!